# Is this desk structurally secure?

Tags: stability, weight-capacity

I've built my first desk using IKEA Adils legs and a worktop I bought and had custom-cut.

It is:

European Walnut
Depth: 40mm
Width: 2900mm
Length: 620mm

Being supported by an Alex drawer on the right-side, a rear-centre mounted Adils leg, and 2 front/back left mounted Adils leg.

I'd say there is about 30kg of weight mounted on the far right side of the desk, but all the weight is either directly on-top of the Alex, or less than 600mm from it. All the weight is also at the rear of the desk, with only my arms weighing on the front (plus a keyboard and mouse).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am just worried the 2 left Adils legs are going to split and the desk will fall.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ikea furniture all comes with some statement of reasonable use. If you hacked or modified the design maybe show a sketch or picture of what you mean, but all commercially available tables come with a basic level of functionality. In short, you are probably fine, but it isn't going to be easy for anyone here to validate that.

Comment: At 40mm (~1.5"), the top isn't likely to split from those 5 or 6 small screws in each leg. Are you worried that the legs themselves are going to fail? I'm not sure what "are going to split" means.

Comment: To echo what @jdv says, it isn't really possible to validate the following in any concrete way, but as the desk stands (i.e. as built, with the weight it's currently holding) I see zero stability issues, presently or future. Now that said, with functional furniture you do need to account for things like the unexpected hip bump, someone sitting on an edge without thinking/due to loss of balance but still I don't see anything of particular concern. A 40mm thick walnut top like this is *hugely* stiff, and the position near a wall limits how far back this could be forced to lean.

Comment: This design has a few important limitations. If you attempt to move the desk, the leg connections could pull out if they are dragged.  Any long term heavy weights near midspan will increase the risk of sagging.  The span between the two back legs is quite long and you may get some sag at the center of the span (Ditto at the front edge). IF it starts sagging you may want to add a few legs to reduce the width of spans.

Comment: @Ashlar, these kinds of legs are obviously a minor concern when it comes to dragging a table, especially over carpet so care would have to be exercised there. But as to sag, this appears to be ABW and it's 40mm thick. That's a smidge over 6/4. I can't see any reasonable scenario where sag could be an issue. Just for solid wood a completely unsupported central span wouldn't sag unacceptably with a 150lb central load, and due to the stave construction this should be significantly stiffer than a slab. Plus there *is* some support mid-span.

Comment: @Graphus Yep you could be right, but the span appears to be 9-10' without any support along the front edge between ends. Mostly I wanted Acrylic to be aware of the possible limitations.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear if this question fits within the purview of "woodworking", and we are only guessing that you are asking "will this walnut stave top split under load or because of fasteners?" With that in mind:

The table is fine. It isn't going anywhere under a static load twice what you've put on it. If you attached the legs with appropriate hardware, ideally into pilot holes, then that is fine.

The thickness and construction of the table top is very robust, and the spans (while longish) are well within acceptable for this construction.

As per the comments, the only thing you have to consider is how this survives any moves or misuse over time. Some furniture, especially flatpack office items, suffer more when being moved than when being actually used. So, as long as you make sure you don't rack the legs beyond what they can take and try not to let the table be a runway for drunken dance parties, it'll be fine.